# mac osx directory with permission d---------

Tags: mac, permissions

I have a strange directory in my disk because of which my system update to 10.6.5 is failing

`degreethem-lm:RemoteManagement jithine$ pwd
/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement

degreethem-lm:RemoteManagement jithine$ ls -l

total 0

drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 May 22  2009 ARDAgent.app/

d---------  3 root  wheel  102 May 22  2009 AppleVNCServer.bundle/`

I tried going to no matter what I do i get permission denied when trying to change the permission to 755 using chmod. I also tried going to single user mode and change the permission but did not work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try repairing the permissions (run Disk Utility, select your boot volume in the sidebar, then the First Aid tab, then click the Repair Disk Permissions button).  This'll reset the permissions of the files installed with the OS back to what they were originally, so it should fix this file and any others that have gotten messed up.

Comment: That failed for the aove mentioned directory. Its says "Error 1: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Is the directory locked or something?  Try `ls -lO` to see if it has any file flags set.

Comment: That was the issue the directory had schg flag set. removing it made it like a normal one under my control ;) Thanks Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

You sure you're trying to chmod it as root? I feel like I've encountered that before... Make sure you've done a disk *repair* in addition, in case something is messed up that isn't letting you change the file permissions. If all of that still fails you may just have to delete it and restore that file from backup or an equivalent system.